# Freshly installed Apache 2.4.10 is failing to construct Debian-style configuration layout in Debian

Tags: debian, configuration, httpd, apache-2.4

I'm on Debian 7. Just built 2.4.10 from source and I'm trying to get the Apache configuration to appear in `/etc/apache2` in the typical Debian distro layout as described [here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout#Debian.2C_Ubuntu_.28Apache_httpd_2.x.29:); however, when I set the `--enable-layout=Debian` configure option, it refuses to comply. Doubly weird is the fact that I've built Apache from source before (2.4.7 on a different box) and it set up the layout as expected.

Maybe it's because it's 2AM and I'm out of coffee, but what am I missing here?

Comment: "It refuses to comply" is **very** vague...

Comment: As in, it does not do what it is advertised to do. It does not lay the apache2 configuration files out in the traditional "Debian" style. Not much more to get than that. I fixed it, however. Just built custom packages with dpkg.